# dplyr - use of indexes for query optimization

Tags: mysql, r, indexing, dplyr

At my job we work with databases (MySQL 5.7.2 predominantly; this is something I can’t change). The task usually is to write complex queries on data sets worth millions of rows. The way it is being done is via flow of MySQL queries building on top of each other (each being a temporary table; with next temporary table building on the previous ones, etc.). As the rows are in millions involving multi-column joins indexing is performed for these temporary tables using alter table statements.

Now, as I try to understand the use of dplyr and explore the power of pipes, it is seemingly a wonderful solution for the kind of problems we solve; i.e., queries building on top of each other. So I have coded simple scripts that leverage the power of dplyr. I send all the queries back to MySQL to evaluate the final outcome (final outcome is only few hundred rows). So all the processing will be done on the remote MySQL server without the need of pulling millions of rows to the local R instance and only the result set will be pulled by the local R instance.

However, I am facing a bottleneck where indexing is needed; and it is absolutely needed due to performance issues. As I see, I can use copy_to function in dplyr which gives me the capability of adding indexes; there are two things bothering me here:

1. I need to create a new table on the remote MySQL server to store the copy_to result (in most scenarios we are only allowed temporary tables).
2. Even if I somehow manage to write a permanent table, copy_to function is not letting me define my own index name as in MySQL; whereas the default name it is coming up with is too long for MySQL to accept (throwing errors on index name length).

Any advice on using indexes with dplyr will be greatly appreciated. Ideally I want something like what is shown in **bold** below:

Tbl1 %>% filter(...) %>% mutate(...) %>%  left_join(Tbl2, by(“col1” = “col1”, “col2” = “col2”) %>%  **add_index(col_from_tbl1, col_from_tbl2)** %>% other operations

BTW, I can see a solution to long index name is to copy_to a new table; then use DBI::dbSendQuery to add index with the name of my choosing; this works. However, the need for indexing is very frequent. This makes the elegance of using pipes disappear, as I need to stop in the mid of pipe chain, copy_to a new table, then add index using dbSendQuery; and then start using pipes again. The whole point of having nice readable code goes away.

Comment: `Paste` and `paste0` might work for you and there is also `sprintf`.  I see that, as you are using a `Tidyverse` function in `dplyr`, you might find that [`glue`](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/10/glue-1.2.0/) is better.

Comment: Pipelining and using lots of temp tables in a sequence is a way to significantly slow down the entire process.  Try to write a single SQL statement.  As with most 3rd party packages, the underlying SQL is the key to performance; the package may actually get in the way.

Comment: Thank you @RickJames. It makes sense. However, I still see the benefits of taking this path: 1) quick query building 2) easy to understand 3) more robust in cases where we need to use the query for couple of analyses and then discard (the up-front time needed for planning a more complex single statement is saved; for a mediocre SQL query writer anyways).

Comment: Well, study the queries and temp tables that dplyr builds for you.  Soon you will get the hang of it, and be about to toss dplyr.   (I spend far too much of my time helping programmers on this forum work around deficiencies of 3rd party packages that "help" them avoid learning SQL.)